# How to AddItem with certain ContentTypeID using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, content-type, event-receivers

I am using PowerShell to add 100 items which need to be of a specific ContentType.

(requirement)
Test my custom events receiver using powershell. The test is to create a list with a custom content type and then add 100 items of that content type.

(background)
I am trying to rule out the reasons for a strange behaviour in list workflows. Support team claims it is caused by our custom AddItem event, which I doubt since the receiver works fine on other lists. My addItem custom event receiver uses the ContentTypeID to initiate a corresponding workflow from another configuration list.

(previous searches) 
[This](http://asadewa.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/adding-a-custom-content-type-specific-item-on-a-sharepoint-list/) thread gives a different answer to my requirement, I don't want to change or update an-already-added item.

(question)  How do I add an item with my content type ID, or create the object with certain CT-ID before adding it because I want to test the "AddItem" event receiver. I created te following pseudocode to clarify what I am looking for:

```
#Pseudo-code:
get CSV "c:\file.csv"
connect to SPList "MyList"
for( file.Item Count )
 Create Item object i;
 set object i.ContentID = 0x001ETC #this!
 MyList.AddItem(object i);
End loop & close connection
```

Answer (score 1):

The action my colleague suggested was to put the content type that I want to use as the default content type from list settings.

It is not exactly how I wanted it but it partially solved the question.